# How to build docker images that can be used for different versions of GPUs

Tags: docker, image, gpu, nvidia

I have developed a PyTorch application that locally runs with the assistance of a GPU 3090.

I am attempting to construct a Docker image with the aforementioned application and launch it on a remote, offline server equipped with an A100 GPU.

Unfortunately, I have encountered an error that reads, "torch.cuda.isavailable() is False".

Can anyone provide insight into what went wrong and suggest potential solutions?